# Insert an auto increment Key to SQL server Compact database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

This is my table `Produit(ID,libelle,prix)`. The ID is auto increment, and this is the insert instructions :

```
cmd.Connection = connexion
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Produit_fini(libelle,prix) values (@libelle,@prix)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@libelle", libelle)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prix", prix)
connexion.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
connexion.Close()
```

After executing that, an error is occured says that I can't insert NULL value to the ID !?

> The column can not contain NULL values. [ Column name = ID,Table name
>   = Produit_fini ]

How can I insert the ID here ?

Comment: Are you sure that the column `Id` is auto incremented; i.e, is declared with `IDENTITY(?, ?)` property?

Comment: I create the table graphically so these are the properties of this column : `AllowDBNull = False`  `AutoIncrement = true` `AutoIncrementSeed = 1` `AutoIncrementStep = 1` `Datatype = System.Int32` `MaxLength = -1`   @MahmoudGamal

Comment: I don't know really, but it should work fine. Can you please try to do it programmatically like `ALTER TABLE Produit_fini ALTER COLUMN ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1);`? then try to insert.

Comment: This Sql request is not allowed I can't excute it ! @MahmoudGamal

Comment: `"The ALTER TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.").`

Comment: Try to use [this tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/) and execute that statement on it.

Comment: I get this error : `Token Line number : 1, Token line offset :46, Token in error = IDENTITY `

Comment: What version of SQL Server compact edition you are using. It seems that this is not supported. You might need to delete that column and populate it again. Also try to navigate to your table `Produit_fini` SQL schema and see if the column `ID` has the `IDENTITY` property or not.

Comment: I use 3.5 version, this is the schema of my table : `CREATE TABLE [Produit_fini]
(
   [libelle] NVARCHAR(100),
   [prix] REAL,
   [ID] REAL NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE [Produit_fini] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__Produit_fini__0000000000000066] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);`
Itried to delete the column and add it again. I can not always do it by using SQL statements

Comment: From this definition, this column `ID` is not defined as auto increment or `IDENTITY`. If this table doesn't have data, try to delete it and create it again and add `IDENTITY (1, 1)` to the `ID` column.

Comment: It works !! Thank you @MahmoudGamal, can you add this comment as answer to validate it

Comment: Done, you are welcome any time, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this column `ID` is not defined with an `IDENTITY` property. But, you won't be able to alter the table to add the `IDENTITY` property.

You have to delete the table (if there is no data on it), and create it again with the column `ID` has `IDENTITY(1,1)`.

You might also need to use [this tool Compactview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/) to be able to run statements against SQL Server compact edition database.